# WITH Queries by ActiveRecord::QueryMethods And Return ActiveRecord_Relation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, active-relation

I'm using [select in with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) query by `find_by_sql`:

```
scope :error_percentage, -> (user_obj) {
  find_by_sql("WITH products_boost_sum AS (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN (city_id =#{user_obj.user.city_id || -1}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN (country_id =#{user_obj.country_id || -1}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS boost_sum FROM products) SELECT *, (CASE WHEN boost_sum = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS error_percentage FROM products_boost_sum")
}
```

The problem this scope is used by other scopes. So I need to return `Active_Relation` Object not an array. 
I checked the [QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) of ActiveRecord, but I can't find a method for `with` Query.

How can I use `with` Query to return ActiveRelation Object? 
If there no queryMethod for it, Is that available by `select` Method?

Answer (score 0):

CTE queries are not supported by Active Record out of the box, but there is a gem that adds support https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/postgres_ext.

Then you can do queries like

```
Score.with(my_games: Game.where(id: 1)).joins('JOIN my_games ON scores.game_id = my_games.id')
```